# Flask Permission access denied showing on sever

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Pages on my flask web app are displaying as usual but the server keeps returning error: Error no 13, Permission Denied.
Can someone help me figure out whats happening here?
Code for my views file:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    login_link = True
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(url_for('personal'))
    return render_template('index.html', login_link = login_link)


@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    my_path = path.split('/')
    login_link = False
    page_title = my_path[len(my_path) - 1]
    page_link = ""
    page_heading = ""
    if page_title == 'today':
        page_title = "Today"
        page_heading = "Events Scheduled for Today"
        page_link = "today.html"
    elif page_title == 'next':
        page_title = "This Week"
        page_heading = "Events for Next Seven(7) Days"
        page_link = "today.html"
    elif page_title == 'personal':
        page_title = "Personal"
        page_heading = "Add Personal Tasks"
        page_link = "addtask.html"
```

code for html that calls the personal page:

```html
<form class="ui form" action="personal" method="" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="field">
          <label>Username</label>
          <div class="ui left icon input">
            <input name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
            <i class="user icon"></i>
          </div>
```

I noticed the server throws the error when it tries to get a favicon.ico file. I certainly wasnt adding anh favicon to my work. Below is the command line server display.

```
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 585-133-842
 * Detected change in 'E:\\My_Andela_Project\\Semantic\\DoWell_Web_App\\dowell\\views.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 585-133-842
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2016 11:11:09] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2016 11:11:10] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\My_Andela_Project\DoWell_Web_App\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\My_Andela_Project\DoWell_Web_App\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "E:\My_Andela_Project\DoWell_Web_App\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "E:\My_Andela_Project\DoWell_Web_App\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
```

Comment: Errno 13 points to a file system permission problem, make sure you have set them right and all your project files can be accessed by the flask process.

Comment: Usually you have a web server on top of _Flask_. Check if the web server is run with necessary user permission.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me fast. As far as i can tell, there are no permissions set on the files or server. But i just noticed some thing at the top of the cmd line server display.
Initial post edited to include the display.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. You've been very helpful. So i solved the problem by actually providing a favicon for my work. I stumbled across a log file fro m the flask directory. So i decided to add a favicon and that solved the problem.

```
\flask\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py:
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css" type="text/css">
   <!-- We need to make sure this has a favicon so that the debugger does
    not by accident trigger a request to /favicon.ico which might
   change the application state. -->
   <link rel="shortcut icon"
```